# Using vagrant & puppet, how to create and restore a database on fresh postgresql-server instance?

Tags: postgresql, puppet

I have fresh provisioned instances of apache and postgres all set to go. I would like to restore a dump or mount a logical volume with data to the postgres instance. Likewise, I'd like to ensure that the dump is written out or the volume unmounted when i bring the instance down.

Can I use a logical volume this way? How should I approach?

I see this:
[How to handle data such as Mysql, web sites sources with Vagrant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698957/how-to-handle-data-such-as-mysql-web-sites-sources-with-vagrant)

Answer (score 0):

The other answer had the following suggestions.  Below I will discuss their implications for PostgreSQL.

> In the current version of Vagrant (1.0.3), you have two main options:
>
> - Use shared folders. You can put your MySQL data directory into a shared folder so that the data comes back onto your host machine. The
>     con of this is that shared folders are actually quite slow compared to
>     the native VM filesystem in VirtualBox, and you can run into weird
>     permission issues as well.
> - Setup a task (rake, make, etc.) to copy your MySQL data to your shared folder on demand. Then, before you decide to destroy your VM,
>     you can run the task to export your data to your shared folder, then
>     you can reimport the data when you bring your VM back up.

The shared folders approach may work, but if you do this you need to be extremely careful with file permissions.  PostgreSQL tends to be very paranoid about this, so you may have to be cautious about group permissions.

I would recommend something based on the second approach with a base backup (using pg_basebackup) since you get a copy of your database.  You can also archive your wal segments to that directory to have something that can be restored on demand to near-present conditions.