# How to sync MySQL changes to host with Vagrant?

Tags: mysql, vagrant, vagrantfile

I have a Vagrant box I've setup that I use on two separate machines (one Windows, the other a Mac).

The html, css, javascript files work fine since I use Git to sync them between the two systems. But what about the MySQL database?

When I run vagrant up it executes the following from the Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    mysql -u username -p password nameofbox < /var/www/name_of_db_dump.sql
SHELL
```

The problem is that if I then make changes to the database (e.g. on a WordPress install where I add a page or install a plugin) this isn't synced.

Is there a best practices way to accomplish this sort of database syncing?

Comment: See here: http://superuser.com/questions/90301/sync-two-mysql-databases.  The best practice is to actually set up replication between the two databases, one as the master, one as a slave. Also this might be helpful: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication.html

Comment: this one is quite old but has good insight http://stackoverflow.com/a/11675271/4296747